# How to fire event when user enter particular location?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location

Generally to get the user current location periodically, we make Thread and write code to getCurrentLocation or we set repeat event in alarm manager.

I want when user enter in particular region, app should trigger event like prompt dialog to user that he is now near to me.

With above both approach, app unnecessarily tries to check whether user's current location matching defined location.

Is there any way by that system automatically fire event when user enter or exist particular region?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: How can I test app for geoFancing? Its a pratical things that i cannot roam with device in city. I need to test by seating on chair. Do u have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of functionality you can use **GeoFences**, you can refer to the google's documentation on this by following link,

```
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html
```

Basically Geofences are,

Geofencing combines awareness of the user's current location with awareness of the user's proximity to locations that may be of interest. To mark a location of interest, you specify its latitude and longitude. To adjust the proximity for the location, you add a radius. The latitude, longitude, and radius define a geofence, creating a circular area, or fence, around the location of interest.

You can have multiple active geofences, with a limit of 100 per device user. For each geofence, you can ask Location Services to send you entrance and exit events, or you can specify a duration within the geofence area to wait, or dwell, before triggering an event. You can limit the duration of any geofence by specifying an expiration duration in milliseconds. After the geofence expires, Location Services automatically removes it.

Comment: How can I test app for geoFancing? Its a pratical things that i cannot roam with device in city. I need to test by seating on chair. Do u have any idea?

Comment: you can reduce the radius and you need to roam some of the distance to test it or if you wanted to track then you need to store that data to server like at what time device enters the location, device latitude,longitude.

Comment: you can test geofencing with emulator, changing location will fire geofencing events.